# Refuse to send email to specific recipients with Postfix

Tags: postfix, blacklist, email

So, right now I am halfway through trying to setup an outgoing-mail blacklist, by way of `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

The problem I am experiencing is that my test emails are being delivered when I am expecting them to be rejected by the system.

Here's the `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_block

myhostname = hostname.domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = hostname.domain.com, hostname.domain.com, , localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

My `/etc/postfix/recipient_block` (this was run through postmap afterwards)

```
personalemail@anotheroneofmydomains.com REJECT
```

And then, I'm sending the test email like so:

```
$ echo test | mail -s "test email, please ignore" personalemail@anotheroneofmydomains.com
```

Postfix has had its conf reloaded, has been restarted a couple times to try and troubleshoot, all to no avail.

A chunk from tailing the `/var/log/mail.log` file reads like so:

```
Sep 25 02:27:17 antares postfix/master[3024]: reload -- version 2.7.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Sep 25 02:27:27 antares postfix/pickup[3104]: C723018770: uid=1001 from=<obsidian>
Sep 25 02:27:27 antares postfix/cleanup[3110]: C723018770: message-id=<20110925092727.C723018770@hostname.domain.com>
Sep 25 02:27:27 antares postfix/qmgr[3105]: C723018770: from=<obsidian@hostname.domain.com>, size=388, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 25 02:27:28 antares postfix/smtp[3112]: C723018770: to=<personalemail@anotheroneofmydomains.com>, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[74.125.47.26]:25, delay=0.35, delays=0.01/0.01/0.12/0.21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1316942848 j50si8227610yhe.128)
Sep 25 02:27:28 antares postfix/qmgr[3105]: C723018770: removed
```

...So, I'm stumped.  I don't see why the email *isn't* being rejected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the mail is sent via the `pickup` service (via sendmail inteface) and so it is an "outgoing" mail. For outgoing mail the `smtpd_*_restrictions` don't apply. These restrictions only apply for "incoming" mails that have been sent via SMTP.

**Edit**
There is even a solution provided by Victor Duchovni (Postfix maintainer): http://marc.info/?l=postfix-users&m=120155612332393&w=1

Comment: Bummer, I guess I was a bit misinformed then when reading through the docs.  Thanks for the link and the info, I guess this is a lost cause that isn't worth the performance drain or timesink.

Comment: @Obsidian_ You **can** get it to work if you don't use sendmail (the interface) as delivery method. Send your mails locally via SMTP and it will work! Have look at [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) to accomplish that.

Comment: Okay, I see.  I'll have to make sure that I can run the various web-apps on the server through local SMTP just fine first though.

Comment: It seems that `transport_maps` can block outbound messages (even those submitted locally) when they're sent to a specific email address using entries like `somebody@example.com error: Recipient does not want your emails`. I wish it supported domain wide entries too.

Answer (score 2):

As @mailq says, the "mail" program does not inject messages via SMTP, the "smtpd_recipient_restrictions" only applies to messages received via SMTP.  So, for example, if you run this you should see it showing the reject:

```
printf 'ehlo hostname.domain.com\nmail from: <user@domain.com>\nrcpt to:' \
    '<personalemail@anotheroneofmydomains.com>\nquit\n' | nc localhost 25
```

This does an SMTP connection via "netcat" (usually called "nc"), and should demonstrate that the block **is** indeed in place.

Perhaps this is enough?  If not, the only way I can come up with to do a rejection for this remote address is to set up a transport that rejects messages sent to it, and then list that address in the transport table to be associated with the rejecting transport.