# Reject emails to specific email addresses with postfix

Tags: postfix, zimbra

I want to reject any inbound email to compromised@example.com, an example more people would want this would be internal distribution groups/aliases.

I've tried header_checks without success:

`zmlocalconfig -e postfix_header_checks="pcre:/opt/zimbra/conf/custom_header_checks"`

contents of /opt/zimbra/conf/custom_header_checks

```
/^To:compromised@example.com/ REJECT Mailbox no longer valid
```

However I still do not get the rejection.

I also tried some of the configuration from [Refuse to send email to specific recipients with Postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/315263/refuse-to-send-email-to-specific-recipients-with-postfix) since he had things configured in reverse which is what I'm looking for.

```
zmlocalconfig -e smtpd_recipient_restrictions=check_recipient_access hash:/opt/zimbra/conf/custom_recipient_blocklist
```

/opt/zimbra/conf/custom_recipient_blocklist

```
compromised@example.com/ REJECT
```

This also did not work as intended.

Comment: Are you trying to reject _incoming_ mail or _outgoing_ mail?

Comment: incoming to compromised@example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was `hash` is not listed in `postconf -m`

Final configuration from [per-address access controls](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html)

```
postconf -e smtpd_recipient_restrictions='reject_non_fqdn_recipient, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unlisted_recipient, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender, check_recipient_access lmdb:/opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_recipient_access, permit'
```

contents of /opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_recipient_access

`compromised@example.com REJECT`

> rcpt to:compromised@example.com
>
> 554 5.7.1 : Recipient address rejected: Access denied

To make changes,

```
echo anotherguy@example.com reject >> /opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_recipient_access
postmap /opt/zimbra/conf/postfix_recipient_access
```